# OpenGL 2.0 rendering multiple objects with the same shader

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, shader

I would like to know how to use the same shader for multiple objects but allow them objects to have a different colour

I have many cubes on the screen which all currently load the same shader, the only difference is when it is draw, I change the cubes colour.  If I set the same _program for all of them, they are become all the same colour.

```
- (void)draw:(float)eyeOffset
{
    // Calculate the per-eye model view matrix:
    GLKMatrix4 temp = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(eyeOffset, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    GLKMatrix4 eyeBaseModelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(temp, self.baseModelViewMatrix);

    if (self.isTransparant)
    {
        glEnable (GL_BLEND);
        glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        //glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    }

    if (self.textureInfo)
    {
        glBindTexture(self.textureInfo.target, self.textureInfo.name);
    }

    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

//See if we are sharing a program shader
    if (self.tprogram)
    {
        glUseProgram(self.tprogram);
    }
    else
    {
        glUseProgram(_program);
    }

    self.modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(self.position.x,self.position.y, self.position.z );//(float)x, (float)y, -1.5f)
    self.modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Scale(self.modelViewMatrix, self.scale.x, self.scale.y, self.scale.z);

    //rotation +=0.01;
    self.modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(self.modelViewMatrix,self.spinRotation, 0.0 ,0.0 ,1.0);

    self.modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(eyeBaseModelViewMatrix, self.modelViewMatrix);

    GLKMatrix3 normalMatrix = GLKMatrix3InvertAndTranspose(GLKMatrix4GetMatrix3(self.modelViewMatrix), NULL);
    GLKMatrix4 modelViewProjectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(self.projectionMatrix, self.modelViewMatrix);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX], 1, 0, modelViewProjectionMatrix.m);
    glUniformMatrix3fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_NORMAL_MATRIX], 1, 0, normalMatrix.m);

    _colorSlot = glGetUniformLocation(_program, "color");
    GLfloat color[] = {
        self.color.x, self.color.y, self.color.z, self.color.a};
    glUniform4fv(_colorSlot, 1, color);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

    if (self.isTransparant)
    {
         glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
         //glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
         glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    }
}
```

//setup for each cube

```
- (void)setup;
{

    glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray);
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(gCubeVertexData), gCubeVertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 32, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 32, BUFFER_OFFSET(12));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 32, BUFFER_OFFSET(24));

    glBindVertexArrayOES(0);

}
```

Shader

```
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec3 normal;
uniform vec4 color;

varying lowp vec4 colorVarying;

uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;

void main()
{
    //vec4 diffuseColor = color;

    vec3 eyeNormal = normalize(normalMatrix * normal);
    vec3 lightPosition = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    //diffuseColor = vec4(0.4, 0.4, 1.0, 1.0);

    float nDotVP = max(0.7, dot(eyeNormal, normalize(lightPosition))); // 0.0

    colorVarying = color * nDotVP;

    gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * position;
}
```

I thought uniform vec4 color; allowed me to change the colour at anytime and if every object has a shader, it works fine, I can change object colours on the fly

Comment: I am running that code in the draw function and so it should be updating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about sending a different uniform for each cube (say `uniform vec4 cubeColor` and use it in your fragment shader) before calling `glDrawArrays()` on it ?

Alternatively, you could consider uploading, for each cube, both vertices and vertex colors during the setup then, when drawing, bind the appropriate vertex buffers (e.g. `attribute vec3 a_vertex`) and vertex-color buffers (e.g. `attribute vec4 a_vertexColor`, which you assign, in your vertex shader, to  `varying vec4 v_vertexColor` and use in your fragment shader as `varying vec4 v_vertexColor`).

Also, as a side note, if you're planning to use the same program, you can call `glUseProgram()` once, during the setup (OpenGL is based on a *state machine*, which means that it *recalls* certain parameters (aka. *states*, such as the current program) as long as you don't change them). This might enhance the performance of your program a little bit ;-)

Good luck.

Comment: There's a variation of the `attribute` approach that should generally be more efficient if the color is the same for the whole primitive. Instead of adding the color to the vertex buffer, set the value of the color attribute before the draw call, using a call like `glVertexAttrib4f`.

Comment: I added the actual drawing code so you get a better idea

Comment: I cant find a iOS example of glVertexAttrib4f

Comment: I still think that `uniform` is the way to go if you want something that is constant for a given number of vertices (i.e. until calling `glDrawArrays()`), I would recommend using `glUniform4f()` or `glUniform4fv()` (more infos under `glUniform` in the [Reference Pages](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/), but basically, you could just say `glUniform4f(colorUniformID, r, g, b, a)` before calling `glDrawArrays()` for your cube). Also, since you're developing for iOS, you can always find useful tips in the [OpenGL ES Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/opengl-es/)

Comment: The fix was glVertexAttrib4f(2,self.color.x, self.color.y,self.color.z, self.color.a);